# Why can one cert create profile provision and not the other cert?

Tags: ios, xcode8

I have two certs on my system - one personal and one dev expired and turned to personal. I'm developing apps with Cordova and running them with Xcode on my iPhone to get a preview. I sign the app with the used-to-be-dev cert and there is no problem, however I sign the app with the personal cert and I get:

[image: error cert]

In the hopes to straighten this: I granted everyone the read&write rights to the folder, like below:

[image: folder rights]

to no avail. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is not necessarily local permissions, but permissions with Apple Developer.

Try to sign in at http://developers.apple.com and verify your permissions.

Also, it looks like that bundle identifier cannot be used. (anymore?) Try using another bundle identifier and see if the problem resolves.

Comment: The cert has expired, but I can still create provisioning profiles with it.

Comment: You don't generally use a certificate to generate provisioning profiles. It is simply referenced in the provisioning profile, and will probably fail on build time. But do a double check in the developers portal if you're entitled to create certificates and provisioning profiles. If that's the case, the only option is to change your bundle identifier (or try to remove the app identifier in the portal).

Comment: The portal doesn't show it anymore, because it expired.